# Kafka Streams - ACLs for Internal Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to setup a secure Kafka cluster and having a bit of difficulty with ACLs.

The Confluent security guide for Kafka Streams (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html) simply states that the Cluster Create ACL has to be given to the principal... but it doesn't say anything about how to actually handle the internal topics.

Through research and experimentation, I've determined (for Kafka version 1.0.0):

1. Wildcards cannot be used along with text for topic names in ACLs. For example, since all internal topics are prefixed with the application id, my first thought was to apply an acl to topics matching '<application.id>-*'. This doesn't work.
2. Topics created by the Streams API do not get read/write access granted to the creator automatically.

Are the exact names of the internal topics predictable and consistent? In other words, if I run my application on a dev server, will the exact same topics be created on the production server when run? If so, then I can just add ACLs derived from dev before deploying. If not, how should the ACLs be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the exact names of the internal topics predictable and consistent? In other words, if I run my application on a dev server, will the exact same topics be created on the production server when run?

Yes, you'll get the same exact topics names from run to run. The DSL generates processor names [with a function](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ed971fd4341f1643cba38684a0be3f9362e9394c/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/InternalStreamsBuilder.java#L165) that looks like this:

```
public String newProcessorName(final String prefix) {
    return prefix + String.format("%010d", index.getAndIncrement());
}
```

(where `index` is just an incrementing integer). Those processor names are then used to [create repartition topics](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ed971fd4341f1643cba38684a0be3f9362e9394c/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImpl.java#L661) with a function that looks like this (the parameter `name` is a processor name generated as above):

```
static <K1, V1> String createReparitionedSource(final InternalStreamsBuilder builder,
                                                final Serde<K1> keySerde,
                                                final Serde<V1> valSerde,
                                                final String topicNamePrefix,
                                                final String name) {
    Serializer<K1> keySerializer = keySerde != null ? keySerde.serializer() : null;
    Serializer<V1> valSerializer = valSerde != null ? valSerde.serializer() : null;
    Deserializer<K1> keyDeserializer = keySerde != null ? keySerde.deserializer() : null;
    Deserializer<V1> valDeserializer = valSerde != null ? valSerde.deserializer() : null;
    String baseName = topicNamePrefix != null ? topicNamePrefix : name;

    String repartitionTopic = baseName + REPARTITION_TOPIC_SUFFIX;
    String sinkName = builder.newProcessorName(SINK_NAME);
    String filterName = builder.newProcessorName(FILTER_NAME);
    String sourceName = builder.newProcessorName(SOURCE_NAME);

    builder.internalTopologyBuilder.addInternalTopic(repartitionTopic);
    builder.internalTopologyBuilder.addProcessor(filterName, new KStreamFilter<>(new Predicate<K1, V1>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(final K1 key, final V1 value) {
            return key != null;
        }
    }, false), name);

    builder.internalTopologyBuilder.addSink(sinkName, repartitionTopic, keySerializer, valSerializer,
        null, filterName);
    builder.internalTopologyBuilder.addSource(null, sourceName, new FailOnInvalidTimestamp(),
        keyDeserializer, valDeserializer, repartitionTopic);

    return sourceName;
}
```

If you don't change your topology—like, if don't change the order of how it's built, etc—you'll get the same results no matter where the topology is constructed (presuming you're using the same version of Kafka Streams).

> If so, then I can just add ACLs derived from dev before deploying. If not, how should the ACLs be added?

I have not used ACLs, but I imagine that since these are just regular topics, then yeah, you can apply ACLs to them. The [security guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html) does mention:

> When applications are run against a secured Kafka cluster, the principal running the application must have the ACL --cluster --operation Create set so that the application has the permissions to create internal topics.

I've been wondering about this myself, though, so if I am wrong I am guessing someone from Confluent will correct me.

Comment: You can get the internal topic names via `Topology#describe()`

Comment: Yes. The application should be allowed to create topics. If you don't want to give this privilege, you can also create all internal topics manually before starting the application. If the topics are there, the application will not try to create them, but use them. Note, that you must create the topics with the correct number of partitions -- otherwise, the application will fail.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! For an initial deployment, it seems that knowing the names will work alright, but upgrading could get messy if you don't want to use a new app id. I'm thinking of adding a command-line option to my app to do a describe against the target cluster and print out ACLs necessary to run, using Topology#describe(). Will repartition topics always be listed as a sink?

Comment: "Will repartition topics always be listed as a sink?" -- yes (and as source, too). About ACL with wildcards -- feel free to file a JIRA.